# Integrating a C executable file with html

Tags: javascript, html, c, shell

I have a C executable file which I want to integrate with a GUI. I will be keeping the executable file in C on the server side.

I want to upload a file as an input and have a button on HTML, with the click of the button program should run on the server side. The executable file of C program works on the input file and generates a set of files which will be available to view as an output to the client.

Majorly I want to know the ways I can integrate the C program with HTML.

One idea, was to run a shell script from a PHP file at the click of a button, and the shell script would execute the C program file. But I want to avoid the use of shell scripts in the process.

Could any of you suggest any other ways or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: How is this related to Javascript or Java?

Comment: JavaScript could be used to Ajax to the server. I removed the JAVA tag

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the input..

Comment: @mplungjan could you expand on your answer with respect to Javascript and Ajax being used in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing it, I'd write Python bindings for the C function. Then write a Python Web handler to call your C function and generate a response for the client.

No shell required.

Comment: do you mean c function or binary file ? I have a binary file .exe which is basically C code.

Comment: What do you mean by "basically C code"? Do you have access to the source?

Comment: exe file is made up of a C program. I do have access but the logic of C program is unclear to me. At present I have exe in my hand and I want a web front end so that I can integrate it with C.
This exe file takes input a text file and in output it gives number of text files.

Comment: Please don't be offended - you have the C source-code but you don't understand C well enough to know how it works (entry point etc)? If that's the case, writing bindings for it might be outside your ability level for the time being.

Comment: You can probably get satisfactory results by invoking the executable as a subprocess (and reading standard-out) from whatever language you write your web handler in (e.g. subprocess.call in Python)

Comment: Its alright. Thanks @eddiewould. Do you have any other method in mind, so that I can get this work

Comment: See my comment above. You can use Python's subprocess.call w/out a full shell.